# Detect browser for jQuery Mobile support

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, browser

I developed a mobile web site using jQuery Mobile (and ASP.NET MVC server-side).

But now, when I test it in some devices, I see that it not works in older browsers, for instance, browsers in symbian OS. Another browser that I check that is not supported is Opera Mini.

So for now, I would like to be able to detect if the device/browser supports my web site, if not I just want to show some message saying that the browser isn't supported.

Is there some known approach to do that? Any help will be appreciated :)

If someone has some tips to increase the jQM support for more browsers/devices, it will be very appreciated as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
Use gradeA condition which returns true or false.

   $(function(){
    alert($.mobile.gradeA()); 
   });

See the below link to check A-grade Browsers

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/
```